# How to find the first day of next month,if the current month is december

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm using the following query to get the next month.

```
int theMonth = ((System.DateTime)periodStartDate).Month+1;
```

But if the periodstartDate month id=s december,the above statement throws error.

Comment: does really this line throw an error?

Comment: `((System.DateTime)periodStartDate).AddMonth(1);`.  `Month` property has no setter

Comment: Your first day should be always "1"... Am I wrong?

Comment: Just use `periodStartDate.AddMonths(1)`

Comment: @Nelson Reis: What I was thinking :)

Comment: Datetime.Month return a simpe int32 type! Adding 1 give 13. You have to handle your own mouth type.

Comment: @andrewsimon, are you looking for the day of the week of the first month, as in Thurday is the first day of the month for december?

Answer (score 59):

I think you can get it in this fashion

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2011,12,2);
DateTime dayone = new DateTime(dt.AddMonths(1).Year, dt.AddMonths(1).Month, 1);
```

Now you have a proper `DateTime` object to the first of the next month, do as you please with it

Answer (score 26):

The expression `((System.DateTime)periodStartDate).Month+1` doesn't throw an error if the month is December - it just returns 13. I suspect you're doing this:

```
var nextMonth = new DateTime(periodStartDate.Year, periodStartDate.Month + 1, 1);
```

That would throw an error.

Try this instead:

```
var nextMonth = new DateTime(periodStartDate.Year, periodStartDate.Month, 1)
    .AddMonths(1);
```

Answer (score 13):

I like V4V's answer, but I write it this way:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2011,12,2);
DateTime firstDayNextMonth = dt.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-dt.Day+1);
```

For example, I might be computing a future time and this code does that without stripping out the time part.

Per hvd's most astute comment, this code should be:

```
DateTime dt = new DateTime(2011,12,2);
DateTime firstDayNextMonth = dt.AddDays(-dt.Day+1).AddMonths(1);
```

Comment: You're assuming `dt.AddMonths(1).Day` is the same as `dt.Day`. Consider what happens when you're on e.g. Jan 31st.

Comment: Great observation.  I have modified by answer.

Comment: @hvd - The first example is exactly how I had written it. Took me an hr to figure out what was going on.  In my case what happened what out of memory exception as the calendar rendered January in an infinite loop -.-

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, as it catters for december brilliant answer there @sympatricgreg very helpful.

Answer (score 9):

```
int theMonth = ((System.DateTime)periodStartDate).AddMonths(1).Month;
```

Comment: This is the correct answer if you want to get the next month. Maybe that's what he's looking for.

Answer (score 7):

The trick part is to understand the start date could not start in the first day of the current month, so a plain `AddMonth` could lead to undesired dates. Build a new DateTime in the day 01 and, then, add the month.

```
var firstDayNextMonth = new DateTime(startDate.Year, startDate.Month, 1).AddMonths(+1);
```

BTW, the [`AddMonths` method documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.datetime.addmonths(v=vs.110).aspx) states:

> The AddMonths method calculates the resulting month and year, taking into account leap years and the number of days in a month, then adjusts the day part of the resulting DateTime object. If the resulting day is not a valid day in the resulting month, the last valid day of the resulting month is used. For example, March 31st + 1 month = April 30th, and March 31st - 1 month = February 28 for a non-leap year and February 29 for a leap year.

Answer (score 2):

First date of next month, time 00:00:00

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1);
DateTime dayone = new DateTime(dt.Year, dt.Month, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

after you compute `theMonth`, check whether it equals to 13 (the month after December) and replace the value with 1:

```
theMonth = theMonth==13 ? 1 : theMonth;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you call `AddMonths(1)` then .NET will automatically roll the date into the next year.

```
periodStartDate.AddMonths(1).Month;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code:

```
var newDaye = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-DateTime.Now.Day + 1); //first day in next month
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime nextMonth;
        if(now.Day > 1)
         nextMonth = now.AddDays(-(now.Day - 1)).AddMonths(1);
        else
         nextMonth = now.AddMonths(1);
```

Where Now is the Date you want to start ,you could replace with TheStartPeriod

Answer (score 0):

```
DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
Console.WriteLine(date);
// Sunday 28.06.2015 г. 10:22:41 ч.

int monthsBack = -1;
int whichDay = 1;
// It means -> what day the first day of the previous month is.
DayOfWeek FirstDayOfWeek = date.AddMonths(monthsBack).AddDays(whichDay).DayOfWeek;
Console.WriteLine(FirstDayOfWeek);
// Friday

int delta = DayOfWeek.Monday - date.AddMonths(monthsBack).AddDays(whichDay).DayOfWeek;
Console.WriteLine(delta);
// -4
//-4 ->Monday , -3 ->Tuesday, -2 ->Wednesday , -1 ->Thursday, 0 ->Friday
```

Answer (score -2):

```
    DateTime nextMonthStartDate= DateTime.Parse(startdate.Year + "-" + startdate.AddMonths(1).Month + "-01");
```

This will work in leap year or non leap year. In the  above  converting strings to date time with static date 1 coz always taking start of the month.  Hope it is useful

Comment: Please describe in your answer, what was the problem, and how will this snippet solve it, to help others understand this answer